# trying to set the source of an img tag to something locally via input type file with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

So, i what i did was have upload File box which will allow you to select a file to upload.  This will then point to a file such as: "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"
What i then want to do it have an image tag have its soruce to that file.

```
var filepath = data.value;   //data is the file. returns above C:\\
var value = "file:\\\\" + filePath;
$imgTag.attr("src",value);
return;
```

I am fairly certain this was going to work, but it seems not.  What do you all do?

This is something that would need to be used in IE7+ and unless i am mistaken, HTML5 is not applicable to that browser type.

**Update: It seems to show the little green icon in the image tag that shows it is being referenced correctly now but it seems that it just isn't showing.  Is there somethign that i am not doing right to show the image?**

Answer (score 0):

Html5 allows you to read files that are selected in a file element.  You can then display that data in a img element.  but you can't reference an image on the users system directly.
--found example: http://www.xul.fr/en/html5/filereader.php

for IE, the only thing i can think of is having the file element in an iframe, uploading as soon as it selected and having the server return the file.

There might be a better way, but i don't know it. I think you'd need flash or something with more privileges to perform that.

Comment: This has to be something usable back to IE7